# readObject intermittent classCastException thrown

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, casting

I am developing simple Android to Java app, where i want them to communicate with class Message as shown:

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 120L;
private MessageType type;
private Object content;

public Message(MessageType type, Object content) {
    this.type = type;
    this.content = content;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    string.append(type).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    if (content != null) {
        string.append(content.toString());
    }
    return string.toString();
}
//======== Getters and Setters ===========
...
```

}

Object content is always type User which is very simple.

Now, Java server receives Android requests for registration, and answers with list of available users.
There is some other request/response communication but it is not focus here.

Now, sometimes i have no problem with communication between Android clients and Java server, but sometimes classCastException is thrown (either on Android and Java).

I have two threads on both sides for sending and receiving messages on the same socket.
Do i have to make two separate sockets for sending and receiving which i doubt?

Does anyone has an idea or some experience with that?
Is it connected with multithreading or internet connection weakness?

**EDIT:**
Type for `content` field in Message is Object for flexibility (i will need it to pass some other classes here, but for now, i always send User class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 123L;
private String name;
private String IP;
private int tcpPort;
private int bufferSize;

public User(User user) {
    this.name = new String(user.name);
    this.IP = new String(user.IP);
    this.tcpPort = user.tcpPort;
    this.bufferSize = user.bufferSize;
}

public Integer getHashCode() {
    return ((String) (IP + tcpPort)).hashCode();
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    string.append(name).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    string.append(IP).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    string.append(tcpPort).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    return string.toString();
}
```

Here is simple User class.

Here is what i do on server-side:
- Server receives waits for new requests from clients and adds it to the list of new connections - `Waiter.pendingConnections` (if statement).
- If no new request came thread goes to receiving new messages from existing connections also with soTimeout period.
NOTE: `ClientTcpConnector` and `ServerTcpConnector` are wrappers for sockets, input and output streams and stuff (i will not post those classes because of complexity, for now...)

```
public class DispatchingManager extends Thread {
    private final static Logger Log = LogManager.getLogger(Connector.class.getName());

    private static final int SERVER_WAITING_PORT = 50001;
    public static final ServerTcpConnector syncConnector = new ServerTcpConnector(SERVER_WAITING_PORT);
    private final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT_PERIOD = 300;

    @Override    public void run() {
        /* InetAddress remoteIPaddress = syncConnector.waitConnection(); */
        ClientTcpConnector awaitedConnector;
        boolean isReceived = false;
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            //wrapper for socket.accept() with soTimeout argument
            awaitedConnector = syncConnector.waitRequest(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_PERIOD);
            if (awaitedConnector != null) {
                Log.debug("New connection - available");
                awaitedConnector.connect();
                awaitedConnector.receive();
                Waiter.pendingConnections.addFirst(new CompleteUser(null, awaitedConnector));
            } else {
                for (CompleteUser user : Waiter.onlineConnections.values()) {
                    awaitedConnector = (ClientTcpConnector) user.getConnector();

                    isReceived = awaitedConnector.receive(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_PERIOD);

                    if (isReceived) {
                        Log.debug("Message received from: " + user.getNetworkUser().getName());
                        Waiter.pendingConnections.addFirst(user);
                        isReceived = false;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My server is designed to have few threads which take requests from `Waiter.pendingConnections` and process them with responses to clients. For now i have only one thread processing pending connections.

On the client side is this (very similar):
Here is the main thread after WelcomeActivity.

```
...

@Override
    public void run() {
        tcpConnector = new TcpConnector(remoteServerIP, remoteServerPort);
        while (true) {
            registerWithServer();
            sendTCPThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendDataToServer();
                }
            }, "sendTCPThread");
            sendTCPThread.start();
            waitNewServerMessages();
            sendTCPThread.interrupt();
        }
    }

private void sendDataToServer() {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            try {
                Message message = getSendingMessageQueue().takeFirst();
                tcpConnector.send(message);
                Log.d(TAG, "Sent message - " + message.toString());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean waitNewServerMessages() {
        Message newMessage;
        while (!syncManager.interrupted()) {
            newMessage = (Message) tcpConnector.receiveObject();
            if (newMessage != null) {
                switch (newMessage.getType()) {
                    case NEW_USER:
                        onlineUsers.add((User) newMessage.getContent());
                        updateUIWith((User) newMessage.getContent(),
                                     AppState.IDLE);
                        break;

                    case END_ADDING:
                        break;

                    case DISCONNECTED_USER:
                        updateUIWith((User) newMessage.getContent(),
                                     AppState.DISCONNECTED_USER);
                        break;

                    case DISCONNECT:
                        syncManager.interrupt();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Receive message - " + newMessage.toString());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Basically this is structure of receiving and sending messages, code is too long to be posted completely, but i can do it...

The biggest problem is that i can finish communication sometimes, but sometimes i cannot... I know that me sending receiving code is ok because everything is ok sometimes. But on the other side i don't know how to debug it because it throws this exception sometimes:

```
    11:48:34.002 [Thread-1] DEBUG networkUtils.connectors.Connector - ClassCastException: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to networkUtils.networkMessage.Message
    at networkUtils.connectors.ClientTcpConnector.receive(ClientTcpConnector.java:42) [bin/:?]
    at networkUtils.connectors.ClientTcpConnector.receive(ClientTcpConnector.java:75) [bin/:?]
    at networkUtils.DispatchingManager.run(DispatchingManager.java:37) [bin/:?]
11:48:34.609 [Thread-1] DEBUG networkUtils.connectors.Connector - ClassCastException: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: networkUtils.beans.User cannot be cast to networkUtils.networkMessage.Message
    at networkUtils.connectors.ClientTcpConnector.receive(ClientTcpConnector.java:42) [bin/:?]
    at networkUtils.connectors.ClientTcpConnector.receive(ClientTcpConnector.java:75) [bin/:?]
    at networkUtils.DispatchingManager.run(DispatchingManager.java:37) [bin/:?]
11:48:35.219 [Thread-1] DEBUG networkUtils.connectors.Connector - ClassCastException: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: networkUtils.networkMessage.MessageType cannot be cast to networkUtils.networkMessage.Message
    at networkUtils.connectors.ClientTcpConnector.receive(ClientTcpConnector.java:42) [bin/:?]
    at networkUtils.connectors.ClientTcpConnector.receive(ClientTcpConnector.java:75) [bin/:?]
    at networkUtils.DispatchingManager.run(DispatchingManager.java:37) [bin/:?]
```

I know where is the problem, but i don't know why it happens. :(

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: how do you write and read the messages?

Comment: Throws an exception?  Show us the stack trace!  Show us the implementations of methods that are named in the stack trace!  (At least, anyway, the ones near the _root cause_ of the exception.

Comment: you need to make sure the class used for serialization and deserialization is exactly the same

Comment: Class is the same, my code works in 7/10 runs. But in these 30% it throws exception...

Comment: You haven't posted the code that actually sends and receives these objects. Question is unanswerable.

Comment: Guys, thank you very much, but i found the problem. It was the soTimeoutSocket which interrupts the receiving stream so data was sometimes corrupted.